# Why does my while loop produce an extra value in Java?

Tags: java, while-loop, linked-list, counter

I am trying to create a while loop in Java that counts the number of nodes in a doubly linked list. However my while Loop is producing an extra value and I can not seem to figure out why. Could someone please help me?

The method below is used to count the number of nodes in a list I defined in the Main Method. I called the getListSize() method, in the main method.

```
 public static <E> int Size(Linked<E> L) { 

      int counter=0;
      while (L.header != null && L.header != L.trailer)
      {
        L.header= L.header.getNext();
        counter++;
        
      }
      return counter;
  }


public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     Linked<String> list = new Linked<String>();
     list.addFirst("1");  
     list.addFirst("4");
      list.addLast("3");
      list.addLast("2");
      
            
      System.out.println(Size(list));
      
  }
```

But I get an output of 5 instead of 4

Node and Linked Classes

---

public class Linked {

```
  public static class Node<E> {

    private E element;               
    private Node<E> prev;           
    private Node<E> next;            

    
    public Node(E e, Node<E> p, Node<E> n) {
      element = e;
      prev = p;
      next = n;
    }

    public E getElement() { return element; }

    public Node<E> getPrev() { return prev; }

    public Node<E> getNext() { return next; }

    public void setPrev(Node<E> p) { prev = p; }
    public void setNext(Node<E> n) { next = n; }
    
  } 


  
  public Node<E> header;                    
  public Node<E> trailer;                   
  private int size = 0;                      

  
  public Linked() {
    header = new Node<>(null, null, null);      
    trailer = new Node<>(null, header, null);   
    header.setNext(trailer);                    
  }
```

}

Comment: This appears to be a custom implementation of a doubly linked list.  Are you sure you do not have a bug in its implementation?  Perhaps you should show that code.

Comment: What is the use of `L.header != L.trailer`? Seems like you won't count the last node, yet you said the output is 5 instead of 4.

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't be changing L.header like that.  You're overwriting your head pointer, the list will be useless.  Instead, make a variable pointer = l.header at the beginning of the function and set the value of that.

Comment: @MostNeededRabbit The L.header != L.trailer checks if the head and tail of the list is the same, meaning that there would be only one element in the list. If I remove it then I get an output of 6

Comment: @GabeSechan Thank you, Ill make those changes

Answer (score 0):

We shouldn't care if the header and trailer are the same since the node will have `next = null`.

Code:

```
public static int size(Linked<Node> L) {
    int counter = 0;
    Node curr = L.header;

    while (curr != null) {
        counter++;
        curr = curr.next;
    }

    return counter;
}
```

Examples:

```
Node a = new Node("A");
Linked<Node> linked = new Linked<>(a, a);

System.out.println(size(linked)); // 1

--------------------------------------
Node a = new Node("A");
Node b = new Node("B");
a.next = b;
Linked<Node> linked = new Linked<>(a, b);

System.out.println(size(linked)); // 2

--------------------------------------
Node a = new Node("A");
Node b = new Node("B");
Node c = new Node("C");
a.next = b;
b.next = c;
Linked<Node> linked = new Linked<>(a, c);

System.out.println(size(linked)); // 3
```

Comment: I adjusted my code to the one above but my Output is now 6 instead of 4. Everything you did makes sense to me but I cant understand why my output returns the wrong number

Comment: @kia Can you please share the `Linked` , `Node` classes? I think the problem lies there.

Comment: I've added the classes above

Answer (score 0):

At least part of your problem is because you're adding two "empty" nodes to the list, and then you count them.  This is a weird way of doing things.

You haven't shown us your `add()` method so there's possibly more bugs lurking.

```
  public Linked() {
    header = new Node<>(null, null, null);      // <- Extra   
    trailer = new Node<>(null, header, null);   // <- Extra   
    header.setNext(trailer);                    
  }
```

This is weird enough that I think your instructor may have given you special instructions how to deal with these extra nodes.  You might want to consult with your instructor, there might have been part of a lecture you missed.

BTW, these two nodes won't compare as `==` so you can't use that to end your iteration.  I also notice that your list is circular.  The tail points to the header, and the header is set to point to the trailer.  That is also weird, and again I think you should ask your instructor for clarification, the code you wrote doesn't seem to take this into consideration.

Also, as Gabe pointed out, you appear to be overwriting the value of `header` during your counting.  This will foul everything up.

```
 public static <E> int Size(Linked<E> L) { 

      int counter=0;
      Node<E> current = L.header;
      while (current != null && L.header != L.trailer)
      {
        current = L.header.getNext();
        counter++;
        
      }
      return counter;
  }
```

And finally, the code above is still wrong.  I think your instructor wrote that "weird" code specifically to prevent you from copying code straight off the internet.  There's some addition thinking that needs to be done here.  I've given you one hint (about `L.header` being overwritten) but I think you should talk to your instructor about the rest.

Comment: Thank You, I understand. The code actually was provided by the professor and we were asked to simply create a method to count the number of Nodes in the list. I completely overlooked the fact that 2 empty nodes were created. This has helped a lot.

Comment: Well, a fundamental skill when debugging is reading other people's code, so it's good to pay attention to how they do things.